# Is cat the only reliable command that can read data from serial?

Tags: command-line, tty, cat, serial-port, head

I have a scale that continuously send data via serial port, 2 times per second. The only reliable way on reading this data happened to be `cat` command. The following works:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But the problem with `cat` is that, as it doesn't receive an `EOF`, it continues retrieving data. I've also tried `head`, `read` and `tail`.

```
head -1 /dev/ttyUSB0 | strings
```

works 'almost' everytime, but now and then shows old data, and only re-running cat command fixes it (?). The string after pipe retrieves only printable data.

```
read line < /dev/ttyUSB0 | echo $line
```

now and then retrieves data, but most of the time only shows an empty line.

```
tail -1 < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

just freezes, waiting for `EOF`, maybe?

My issue is that i need to write a `bash` script that can be called and "read" `/dev/ttyUSB0` and retrieve data. I'm going to use `head`. But I'm wondering, as `cat` never fails, if there's a way to capture only one line of `cat` output and then stop it.

Note: the port configuration is 9600 baud, 1 start bit, 8 data bits, no parity, 2 stop bits. To set the port properly this is the command:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 -parity cs8 cstopb
```

Comment: Did you try `dd` ? It might work (with suitable options).

Comment: Your `head` command may be getting slightly old data due to a buffer, and you are reading the top of it.  When you tried `tail`, it was with other arguments.  Try repeating the `head` command options with `tail`

Comment: Thank Basile, I'll investigate dd. Ivan, I agree with you. I've assumed that I'm reading some kind of buffer of stdout. ¿is there a way to reset it?. And don't understand why cat isn't affected with this buffer issue. Thank you. I've used head -10 /dev/ttyUSB0 | tail -1. But  get the same result, erratic.

Comment: Try prefixing a non-`cat` command with `stdbuf  -i 0 -o 0`, *i.e.* `stdbuf  -i 0 -o 0 head -1 /dev/ttyUSB0 | strings`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to place the tty in raw mode, and write a program that discards characters until it sees the start of a message, and then prints characters until it reaches the end of a message. With 'raw' added to the `stty`, `fgetc()` can be used on the tty to get a single character.

off the cuff psuedo:

```
char = fgetc(serial_port);
if char == START_CHARACTER {
    putc(char);
    for (i=0;i<MESSAGE_LENGTH;i++){
        putc(fgetc(serial_port));
    }
}
```

It may also be possible to do this with sed and a raw tty, see this other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943025/how-can-i-get-sed-to-quit-after-the-first-matching-address-range

Comment: thanks you very much KJ4IPS!, i'll try not to "sound" rude, but I lack the vocabulary to "sound polite enough", so excuse me. But the answer you've wrote doesn't solve my problem. The scale already transmits data with 2Hz frequency. Inmediately after been turned on. Constantly. It never stops. So it's not possible to reach an end of message. On the other hand, I'm interested in solving this with pure bash.